# Relationships in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I'm using Entity framework 5 and mvc4 and struggling with the entity framework relationships

I have a User, Role and UserRole table 
[image: SQL Table]
The model is created in Entity framework

[image]

Here is the code I use to save the User and the Role but this doesnt work
The User and Role object properties is set before being passed to this method

```
public void saveNewUser(User u, Role r)
{
    using (FormValueEntities db = new FormValueEntities())
    {
        u.Roles.Add(r);
        r.Users.Add(u);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How do I create a new user and set the Role at the same time?

Comment: Do the user/role exist in the DB already or are they new?  What error are you getting?

Comment: They exist in the DB, I don't get any errors the data just doesn't save in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because the User and Role are not attached to the context you are creating.  So you need to do this sort of thing:

```
User newUser = new User(){ ... Set proprties ...};

db.Users.Add(newUser);

newUser.Roles.Add(r);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Note that you don't need to add the link in both directions explicitly.

Comment: Hi I get this error when I use your code The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_UserRole_User\". The conflict occurred in database \"FormValue\", table \"User.User\", column 'UserId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Comment: Ok, I think that it was thinking that you were trying to add a new user.  See the edits above, can you try?

Comment: Ok thanks that works but it adds the role to the current User, I want to create a new User and assign it a Role

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include the `UserRole` table in your entity. You can simply drag and drop it in the design view.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to update your Entity Framework.

And code :

```
public void saveNewUser(User u, Role r)
{
    using (FormValueEntities db = new FormValueEntities())
    {
        db.Role.Add(r);
        db.User.Add(u);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Membership api:

```
                    const string adminRole = "Administrator";
                    const string adminUserName = "Admin";
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(adminUserName, "123456", null, false);
                    Roles.CreateRole(adminRole);
                    Roles.AddUsersToRole(new string[] { adminUserName }, adminRole);
```